# What is the probability that $S \leq T$?

Tags: stochastic-processes

> Suppose $S$ and $T$ are independent exponential random variables of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. What is the probability that $S \leq T$

Could anyone explain to me how to calculate this? 
$$
\mathbb{P}(S \leq T).
$$
But we only know that $\mathbb{P}(t \leq T) =  e^{-\beta t}$ and $\mathbb{P}(t \leq S) = e^{-\alpha t}$. I was thinking maybe we can condition on $S$ so that we get 
$$
\mathbb{P}(S \leq T) = \mathbb{P}(t \leq T \ | \ S =t) = \mathbb{P}(t \leq T  \ \text{and} \ S = t)/\mathbb{P}(S=t).
$$
Am I on the right track?

Comment: $P(S \leq T) = \int_t P(S = t, T \geq t) dt$

Comment: "But we only know that  $\dots$" is not right. $\beta e^{-\beta t}$ is not the probability that $t\le T$, it is the density function of $T$. The probability that $T\ge t$ is $e^{-\beta t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken in saying $\Pr(t<T) = \beta e^{-\beta t}$.  That should say $\Pr(t<T) = e^{-\beta t}$ (for $t\ge0$), so $\Pr(T<t) = 1- e^{-\beta t}$ (for $t\ge0$), and hence the density is $f_T(t)= \beta e^{-\beta t}$ for $g\ge0$.

\begin{align}
\Pr(S<T) & = \operatorname{E}(\Pr(S<T\mid S)) \\[10pt]
& = \operatorname{E}(e^{-\beta S}) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t} f_S(t) \, dt \\[10pt]
& =\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t} \alpha e^{-\alpha t} \, dt \\[10pt]
& = \alpha \int_0^\infty e^{-(\alpha+\beta) t} \,dt = \frac\alpha{\alpha+\beta}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. But in the third step you compute $E(e^{-\beta S)$ could you explain how you got that integral? The large S becomes a small one and in step 5 it is suddenly gone?

Comment: @Nescrio : There was a typo.  I've fixed it and added a bit. ${}\qquad{}$